# ggplot2: setting guide ticks in scale_color_gradient()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to change x values in the legend below so that they are nice round numbers (e.g. 0.01, 1, 10) instead of the crazy long, seemingly arbitrary decimals. How do I do so?  I generated the plot using the code further below. This seems like there should be a really easy option to set, but I googled around and read the help files and for the life of me, I can't figure it out.

I'm currently using ggplot2_1.0.1.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
d = data.frame(x = 10^seq(-2,2,length.out=10),y=10^(seq(-2,2,length.out=10)))
g = ggplot(data=d,aes(x=x,y=y,group=x,color=x)) + geom_point()
g = g + scale_color_gradient(trans="log",guide="legend")
print(g)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `breaks=` argument to the function `scale_color_gradient()` to set desired levels.

```
ggplot(data=d,aes(x=x,y=y,group=x,color=x)) + geom_point() + 
      scale_color_gradient(trans="log",guide="legend",breaks=c(0.01,1,10))
```